# Android app gives "app not installed" error when opened from menu

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I have built an Android app using Android studio 2.1.2 . I have generated the signed apk and published the same to Google Play store. Users are being able to download and install it. The issue arises after the installation . In some phones(**Galaxy On7,Lenovo A6000 plus**) the app cannot be opened from the menu or the home screen shortcut and the error pops up saying "app not installed", but it opens fine when opened from Play Store. I did some researching but haven't come across a solution for this. Can anyone suggest why this might be happening ?
This is my manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.crm.crmenterprise">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:permission="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
            android:protectionLevel="dangerous">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LeadActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_lead"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes in the manifest file and the app now works perfectly on all phones.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LeadActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_lead"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        </activity>

    </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstall your app.. might be possible that something error occur in you package building

Comment: reinstalling yields the same result

Comment: check in another phones also

Comment: result is same for other phones also

Comment: why are u use.. `android:permission="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
            android:protectionLevel="dangerous">`

Comment: for reading call state.i need to know if user has received an incoming call

Comment: why but you already use in application level same READ_PHONE_STATE permission then whey again...

And why the protectionLevel="dangerous"

Comment: is that the cause of the problem ? If so then why not on all phones ?